# How do I operate on a set of ordered pairs?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a calculation that will give me a lot of ordered pairs. For each such pair in a list, I want to square the elements and add them together. Here is an example of the kind of list I have

```
{{-3 a, 3 a}, {-1 a,  a}, {-1 a, a}, {-1 a,  a}}
```

In this instance I would have `18 a^2` for the first pair and so on.

Comment: There are several options (and many variants have been asked before here)... the simplest: `pairs /. {a_, b_} :> a^2 + b^2`

Comment: you aren't using proper Mathematica syntax. Lists go between `{ }` pairs

Comment: `Plus @@@ (data^2)`. `Power` is `Listable`.

Answer (score 8):

```
data = {{-3 a, 3 a}, {-a, a}, {-a, a}, {-a, a}};
```

rm-rf's comment:

```
data /. {a_, b_} :> a^2 + b^2
```

> {18 a^2, 2 a^2, 2 a^2, 2 a^2}

`Power` is `Listable`, meaning:

```
data^2
```

> {{9 a^2, 9 a^2}, {a^2, a^2}, {a^2, a^2}, {a^2, a^2}}

Thus, Verbeia's comment:

```
Plus @@@ (data^2)
```

> {18 a^2, 2 a^2, 2 a^2, 2 a^2}

Or:

```
Total[data^2, {2}]
```

> {18 a^2, 2 a^2, 2 a^2, 2 a^2}

Perhaps for *Mathematica* newcomers mapping an operator over the list of pairs will seem more intuitive. Let's take this in two steps to make it easy to understand what's going on. First define the operator

```
operator[{x_, y_}] := x^2 + y^2
```

Second map it over the data list

```
Map[operator, data]
```

> {18 a^2, 2 a^2, 2 a^2, 2 a^2}

Of course there is a way to express this in one line which is not so easy to understand.

```
(#1^2 + #2^2)&[Sequence @@ #]& /@ data
```

> {18 a^2, 2 a^2, 2 a^2, 2 a^2}